# Delta formal definition for DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

How can I formally define * for a **dfa** with multiple initial states?
I know that the δ formal definition for NFA is δ: Q × ∑ → 2^Q
and for DFA it's δ : Q × Σ → Q
but what should I do if there is multiple initial states?How can I take into consideration all the options for the initial state?It seem like it should combine the NFA definition and DFA definition.. δ: 2^Q × ∑ → Q maybe?but it doesn't seem right neither.

I would appreciate any help I can get on this matter

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple initial states, then this automata is non-deterministic.

Comment: DFA can't have multiple initial states?

Comment: No. How would you like to define accepting an input in such automata?

Comment: For every input w if  there is a transition function * starting from one of the  initial states and ending with one of the  final states

Comment: Doesn't it sound familiar to definition of accepting in NFA? :)

Comment: The problem is it's  defined in the question as a DFA with multiple initial states..I thought that I might be missing on something here..since I know that for every DFA there is an NFA but I'm not sure that the opposite is also right,I'll try considering it as a NFA :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you right, but [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) could be something you are looking for :)